# Is there a way to use Lightning Components from Salesforce Labs into other Lightning Components?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

There are a lot of free Lightning Components from Salesforce Labs: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=force.com+labs&type=apps

I'm looking into PTO Profile Picture Changer in particular

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q78MEAQ

But also others are interesting.

I want to use this component actually in a Visualforce page and/or inside other Lightning Components or other Standalone Lightning Apps.

My first question: is that possible at all? Or are those components only designed to be used by App Builder and Community Builder and not flexibly inside any other Components?

If yes, then how to figure out the names and parameters?

Answer (score 3):

From how I understand the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_components.htm): access level of the component is determined by whether it's `public` and only accessable in it's own namespace or `global` and accessable in any namespace.
From what I can tell after installing the PTO App only the "lampone:ChartjsChangeChartTypeButton" appears to be global as it shows up in the [Reference Doc App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_doc_app.htm?search_text=reference%20doc%20app)

> https://.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app, where
>    is the name of your custom Salesforce domain.

This is also where you can see which attributes a component has. After installing the [Lightning Utility Pack](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000qDmjEAE), you can see the different components available for use along with their attributes.